# WPF [VB] Bring selected ListViewItem to front and overlap other ListViewItems

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, overlap

I am making an explorer control in my WPF application using a Treeview and Listview. For the Listview I would like to show the contents of the selected folder using 32x32 pixel icons. To achieve this I have the following XAML which is also truncating long file/folder names within a TextBlock:

```
<ListView x:Name="LV_Explore"
    Grid.Column="2"
    BorderThickness="0"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    AllowDrop="True">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="SP_ExploreItem"
                Width="42">
                <Image Source="{Binding LargeIcon, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Margin="0,0,0,2" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="TXT_ExploreItem"
                    Width="42"
                    Height="42"
                    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                    TextAlignment="Center"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                    LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                    Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When selecting a ListViewItem I would like for it to overlap the items (files/folders) below rather than the current behaviour which is to increase the height of all of the ListViewItems in the current row of the WrapPanel.

To get to the ListViewItem I am using the following code in order to show all of the text in the TextBlock when an item is selected:

```
Private Sub LV_Explore_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles LV_Explore.SelectionChanged
    If LV_Explore.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        Dim LVItem As ListViewItem = TryCast(Me.LV_Explore.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(Me.LV_Explore.SelectedIndex), ListViewItem)
        If LVItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim BD As Border = TryCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(LVItem, 0), Border)
            If BD IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim CP As ContentPresenter = TryCast(BD.Child, ContentPresenter)
                If CP IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim SP As StackPanel = TryCast(LVItem.ContentTemplate.FindName("SP_ExploreItem", CP), StackPanel)
                    If SP IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim TB As TextBlock = TryCast(SP.FindName("TXT_ExploreItem"), TextBlock)
                        TB.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.None
                        TB.Height = Double.NaN
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

For reference I want to achieve similar to the behaviour of the desktop e.g: Screenshot 1: [Normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDvUS.jpg) Screenshot 2: [Selected state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4ytd.jpg)

Whereas I currently have the normal state working fine and the selected state appears like this: Screenshot 3: [Listview selected state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r4XV.jpg)

I suspect that I may need to change from using a WrapPanel to a Canvas in the ItemsPanelTemplate of the ListView control which will then lose the behaviour of lining up and wrapping items within the Listview automatically. So I am looking for suggestions of the best approach to use here to maintain the layout and to allow me to overlap items when selected.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

As you may realise, something in a listview item is inside a sort of a box and it isn't getting out of that. It will be truncated or clipped if you don't let it grow.
A canvas doesn't clip so that would tick one box of your requirement, you would have to write a custom panel based on a canvas or the base panel control and write your own measure/arrange code.
This is non trivial and any scrolling could make it even more complicated, but you could take a look at people's work:
eg
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF

Alternately, you could use an adorner.
The adorner layer is on top of everything else in your window but still in the same datacontext of whatever it's associated with.
These are not so easy to work with but again you could base your code on someone else's:

http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/07/12/wpf-adorners-part-4-ndash-simple-and-powerful-system-for.aspx

An adorner would probably be my first candidate, if I follow what you want correctly.

Not many people use vb nowadays and I'm afraid you're going to find pretty much every time you look at samples they are c#.

Comment: `Not many people use vb nowadays and I'm afraid you're going to find pretty much every time you look at samples they are c#.` - This is not true. While C# is more popular, making it easier to find C# examples (which can be converted to VB.NET), that doesn't mean that the amount of people using VB.NET has drastically decreased. Infact, VB.NET is in 6th place (right behind C#) on the [TIOBE index](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/), and has increased in popularity by 1.70% since last april.

Comment: Thank you Andy, Adorner does look like a good solution and something I had not heard about before. Whilst VB examples tend to be quite rare for WPF applications I can read and convert most C# examples easily enough. Once I make some progress on this I will come back and rate the post. Interesting reading about the TIOBE index Vincent - Annoyingly all the jobs in my area advertise for C#, despite the popularity, pushing me to bite the bullet and start converting.